# How should I use 'this' (self) inside a javascript module?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small module by using the following pattern:

```
var inprModal = (function () {

    var validateAndSave = function() {
        var id = $('#Id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: inprModal.url,
            data: {id: id },
            success: function(response) {
            },
        });
    };

    return {
        initialize: function () {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#bSaveItem').click(function() {
                    validateAndSave();
                });
            });
        }

    };

})();

inprModal.url= '123';
inprModal.initialize();
```

I need to assign some parameters externally to be able later to use this value when I create an ajax request:

```
inprModal.url= '123';
```

However, as I call the method validateAndSave from the callback, I have to use the property together with the module name in order to access it:

```
url: testModule.url
```

I would like to avoid such referencing to the method and instead of the module name use this or 'self' properties. However, when I just add a property 'self' to the immediate function, it references Window object:

```
var inprModal = (function () {
    var self = this; // === Window
```

Maybe I should use constructor here, but in many examples of a module pattern I see that it uses just an immediate function without a constructor.

Could you suggest how this can be done better?

Comment: What's the advantage of using the name `self` over using the name `inprModal`? It's a single object, so a generic reference shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Oh, you want a local reference. Didn't see that you didn't have that. In that case, just make a local variable that points to the object you're returning, then return the object using the variable. `var self = {initialize: func...}; return self;`

Comment: I decided on using the approach suggested by Blue Skies, as it was the most clean solution. But I also voted up the idea of PSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a protected reference to your object, just in case the outer scoped `inprModal` is modified.

If so, just save your object within the module to a local `self` variable, and reference it wherever needed

```
var inprModal = (function () {
    var self = { // -- save your object to the self variable
        initialize: function () {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#bSaveItem').click(function() {
                    validateAndSave();
                });
            });
        }
    };
    var validateAndSave = function() {
        var id = $('#Id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: self.url, // -- referenced via self
            data: {id: id },
            success: function(response) {
            },
        });
    };

    return self; // -- return the object
})();
```

There's no need for a generic `this` reference to be used, since it's a single object. JavaScript's `this` semantics would make that a clunky approach.

Comment: This is (sort of) the way I would do it. People always seem to forget that the `return` can be on a different line to the _Object_ you want returned, but doing it this way means you have another reference you can use which is independent of anything outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that when you invoke the method `validateAndSave` from your anonymous callback function it will have the context of global (window) inside the method, You can try this way:

```
 return {
    initialize: function () {
         var self = this;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bSaveItem').click(function() {
                 validateAndSave.call(self); //call it with self
            });
        });
    }
 };
```

Or just do:

```
return {
   initialize: function () {
     var self = this;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bSaveItem').click($.proxy(validateAndSave, self));
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to consider "what is `this`?" because I don't see a `new` anywhere

Comment: @PaulS. I didn't get, what do you mean by that. `this` the way the method is invoked is gng to be guess what... :)

Answer (score -1):

I usually use `bind`

```
var inprModal = (function () {

    var validateAndSave = function() {
        var id = $('#Id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: this.url, // <---
            data: {id: id },
            success: function(response) {
            },
        });
    };

    return {
        initialize: function () {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#bSaveItem').click(function() {
                    validateAndSave();
                }.bind(this)); // <---
            }.bind(this)); // <---
        }

    };

})();

inprModal.url= '123';
inprModal.initialize();
```

Comment: You're binding `this`, but then ignoring it.

Comment: No, I am not ignoring it. `validateAndSave()` use the same context as its caller, which was bound to `this` ...